# SEVERE: A message body reader for Java type, class <classname>, and MIME media type, application/json, was not found

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-1.0

I am creating a REST service with jersey.

Here the request handler class's method.

```
@POST
@Path("/deleteWorkers")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response deleteWorkers(DeleteWorkerPOJO deleteWorkerPOJO) {......}
```

This method gives below error

```
SEVERE: A message body reader for Java type, class <classname>, and MIME media type, application/json, was not found
```

There are some several POST methods in the same class which does not consume POJOs. They are working fine. 
And many developers has suggested, I have added `jersy-json` library and

```
<param-name>
    com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature
</param-name>
<param-value>
    true
</param-value>
```

Still this gives the same error.

Jersey version is 1.2 and java version is 1.5

Comment: Everything _looks_ right. Can you post the complete web.xml, pom.xml (just deps), POJO class, and stack trace?

Comment: sorry If my question is stupid, I am new to this area but is @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) necessary ?